# Using store in interceptors axios? nuxt js

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

I use `interceptors` to catch errors in the application. If catch 401 error, I would like to mutate the state of one of my variables. How to use my `store` inside the axios interceptors? I use axios like plugin in my nuxt-app

Answer (score 0):

```js
// inside my axios configuration
export default function({ $axios, store }) {}
```